# Автозаполнение поля пароль

Tags: php, html, autocomplete

Есть маленькая форма, которая имеет имя, телефон и пароль для редактирования. Так вот. пароль постоянно сам заполняется. К примеру, в firefox. И НИКАК его не убрать, скриптом на document ready значение пустое на выставляется, autocomplete не работает. Как можно оставлять поле пароля пустым всегда при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Если в `about:preferences#security` снимете галку `Запомнить логины для сайтов`, то как себя вести автозаполнение будет?

Answer (score 2):

Сочетайте атрибут `autocomplete="off"` с формированием разных имен поля. Например добавляйте префикс или делайте имя массивом со случайным индексом. Например `name="password9762567"` или `name="password[9762567]"`

Comment: не помогает. Даже с пустым именем форма заполняется. Не могу понять, как работает этот механизм

Comment: @Gleb, браузер подставляет сохранённые значения.

Comment: @Gleb Заполняется при условии постоянно меняющегося имени поля?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего он просто смотрим по `[type="password"]` и запоминает так, не смотря на имя, это вполне логично, если `autocomplete="off"` не помогает, есть ещё один фокус:

Сначала сделать `<input>` только для чтения, а после нажатия на него, убрать этот атрибут:

```
<input type="password" name="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')">
```

Comment: Перепробовал кучу разных вариантов. Этот РЕАЛЬНО рабочий. Респект!

Answer (score 0):

Есть хак, в начале формы записать нечто подобное:

```
<form>
  <input style="display: none">
  <input type="password" style="display: none">
  ...
</form>
```