# Как запретить подтягивать историю заполнения полей веб-форм?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Пользователи проходят регистрацию и мне необходимо запретить подтягивать историю заполнения форм на такие поля ввода, как логин и пароль. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен [атрибут autocomplete](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete):

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off">
```

P.S. Есть и другой способ -- задавать уникальные наименования, посмотрите например вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/489124#489124). Но это не best practice.