# Очистка данных формы после отправки

Tags: php

Есть форма:

```
<form class="callback__form" id="contant__form" action="send.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="urname" placeholder="Ваше имя.." required>
                    <input type="text" name="urtel" placeholder="Ваш телефон.." required>
                    <input type="submit" id="send-post" value="Вызвать мастера">
    </form>
```

Вот скрипт отправки с переходом на страницу благодарности.

```
<?php
    $urname = $_POST['urname'];
    $urtel = $_POST['urtel'];
    $urname = htmlspecialchars($urname);
    $urtel = htmlspecialchars($urtel);
    $urname = urldecode($urname);
    $urtel = urldecode($urtel);

    if (mail("test6@gmail.com", "Заявка", "Имя:".$urname.". Телефон: ".$urtel ,"From: test6@gmail.com \r\n")) {
            header("Location: /thanks.html");
        }

        if(@mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "Отправлено";
          }else{
            echo "Не отправлено";
          }
    ?>
```

Нужно очистить данные в форме после отправки. Пробовал разные способы, но из-за низкого уровня знаний не помогло. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не понятно в чём суть вопроса. Где остаются данные? Вы же перенаправляете пользователя совешенно на другую страницу. А в инпутах нет значений по-умолчанию, тьолько плейсхолдеры.

Comment: @Hast Да, после отправки пользователя перенаправляет на другую страницу, на которой, собственно, благодарность, и кнопка "Вернуться", после нажатия которой в инпутах остаются вводимые данные. Нужно чтобы данные после отправки стирались.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запретить подтягивать историю заполнения полей веб-форм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542472/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Попробуй добавить в инпуты `autocomplete="off"`, чтобы получилось что-то типа такого:

   `<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />`
2. Желательно узнать как работает кнопка "Вернуться". Попробуй сделать её ссылкой

Comment: Кнопка "Вернуться" - ссылка с `href="#" onclick="history.back();"`

Comment: Первый способ не сработал?
Если нет, то можно просто сделать кнопку ссылкой `<a href="form.php">Go back</a>` (где form.php - это урл страницы, где показывает форма)